# How to set an image as a frame for iframe without clipping the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add an image to an iframe but the image is clipping any idea how to fix this?

I tried the following styles:

```
iframe { 
    border:60px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(/images/map-frame.png) 17% round;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
```

what came out [image]

what I was expecting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the borders on an absolutely positioned pseudo element on the container.

> When viewing a code snippet, the frame may take a long time to load, wait for the frame to appear around the image.

```css
  .container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .container::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 40px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6730/5091629.9a/0_7eb4e_e27786d4_XL.png)
      25% round;
    content: '';
  }

  .iframe {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img
    class="iframe"
    src="https://iv.kommersant.ru/Issues.photo/LifeStyle_News/2016/09/07/KLS_000009_00362_1_t222_155007.jpg"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```